# Is there such a thing as wildcards within keytool?

Tags: keytool

I am searching a keystore and I want to list all instances of an alias with say "John" in the alias.  Is there a way to do this just using keytool? using a wildcard or something?  If i use `-alias john` it just comes back and says there is no certs found with that alias.

I have tried `-alias john`, `-alias john*` (in case it took wildcards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java keytool doesn't support wildcard alias. In the keytool source code, it parses out the alias string entered as-is. The highlighted code in the screenshot below is the parsing of the `alias` argument from the command line:

[image]

The `alias` variable is used everywhere by the keytool class without any changes to it.

*The source code screenshot is from decompiled jdk11 source file in Eclipse IDE.*